# How to easily dowgrade python version?

Tags: python, terminal, version

I bought the new M1 mac a couple of months back and found myself kinda stuck as I now have python 3.9.6 but I need packages that require version 3.8. I honestly don't remember how I installed python, pip, and brew as I followed tutorials. How can I downgrade python?

Comment: The typical way of dealing with this is to set up a virtual environment that contains the version of Python you need, along with those packages. Then you use that environment when you need those packages.

Comment: Whatever you do, do *not* downgrade the version that came with the machine. That is for the operating system to manage, not you.

Comment: on some systems you may have many version installed and you don't have to downgrate it. On Linux I have command `python2`, `python3.6`, `python3.7` ... `python3.10` to run code with different versions. The same with `pip2`, `pip3.6` ... `pip3.10`

Comment: Alright thanks guys!